# Adicionar conteúdo à um window.URL.createObjectURL?

Tags: javascript, blob

Eu preciso adicionar conteúdo à um "**window.URL.createObjectURL**" (blob), mas depois de muita pesquisa não encontrei nada relacionado. É realmente impossível?

Acabei usando "**webkitRequestFileSystem**" como alternativa mas é bem obsoleto.
https://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Ficaria feliz com outra alternativa!

Comment: Que tipo de conteúdo vc quer adicionar? Essa função tem como objetivo criar um objeto File que retorna as propriedades de um arquivo selecionado em um input type=file.

Comment: " type: 'text/xml' " fis teste com "MediaSource" usando "addSourceBuffer" e não mim parece ser exclusivo de Medias.